# Kotlin Data Structures and Algorithms

Tags: list, algorithm, kotlin, data-structures, linked-list

```
fun main() {
"creating and linking nodes" example {
    val node1 = Node(value = 1)
    val node2 = Node(value = 2)
    val node3 = Node(value = 3)
    node1.next = node2
    node2.next = node3
    println(node1)
}

"push" example {
    val list = LinkedList<Int>()
    list.push(3)
    list.push(2)
    list.push(1)
    println(list)
}
```

}

So, I'm following Data Structures and Algorithms for Kotlin, First Edition (there's now a Second).

What does the "creating and linking nodes" example {} or the "push" example {} do, exactly?  It is being rejected by the IDE and is definitely not syntax I've seen.  Is this old syntax, deprecated?  If I just remove it, and keep the code contained within the example{}, it appears to work fine, as intended.  Can anyone tell me why I should or would want to keep this?

The following works fine, as far as I can tell, and... for now.

```
fun main() {
// "creating and linking nodes" example {}
    val node1 = Node(value = 1)
    val node2 = Node(value = 2)
    val node3 = Node(value = 3)
    node1.next = node2
    node2.next = node3
    println(node1)


// "push" example {}
    val list = LinkedList<Int>()
    list.push(3)
    list.push(2)
    list.push(1)
    println(list)
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmnQr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vIpR.png

**EDIT:**  Currently the code looks like this, per the suggestion below.  What am I still missing?

```
fun main() {

infix fun String.example(block: () -> Unit) : block()

"creating and linking nodes" example {
    val node1 = Node(value = 1)
    val node2 = Node(value = 2)
    val node3 = Node(value = 3)
    node1.next = node2
    node2.next = node3
    println(node1)
}


"push" example {
    val list = LinkedList<Int>()
    list.push(3)
    list.push(2)
    list.push(1)
    println(list)
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please pick a less generic title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with that... My bet is that `example` is an [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation)

Adding something like

```
infix fun String.example(block: () -> Unit) = block()
```

should make it work

Comment: Output they want always starts with ---Example of [String]--- and then is followed on the next line by 1 -> 2 -> 3

Comment: Adding the above to fun main() did not fully resolve the issue, it did make the other example functions activate, but the block() is now shown in red and being rejected by the IDE.

Comment: `: block()` should be `= block()`. But following David's comment about the output, it should be `{ println("---Example of $this"); block() }`.

Comment: Hm... I think I need to research extension functions and understand them and infix functions to really figure this out.

= block() is the right syntax, removed the red highlight on block()

However, I might be still misusing it or placing it wrong to get the desired output.  Not even sure right now where to put that println you suggested.

Thank you so much for the help though! Very kind.

EDIT: Surprised they don't explain this in the book, very odd, it's used for the entire course as the desired way to show the output from the examples.

Comment: @DavidJones put that println exactly where I show it, i.e. `infix fun String.example(block: () -> Unit) { println("---Example of $this"); block() }`

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!  See edit/update above for image attached.  

Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Yep, correct syntax is `= block()`. Shame on me for writing code directly on SO instead of going through an IDE

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in Utils.kt

```
infix fun String.example(function: () -> Unit) {
  println("---Example of $this---")
  function()
  println()
}
```